# How to send values for a HashMap in SOAPUI?

Tags: web-services, soap, hashmap, soapui

I have a Webservice that receive a HashMap, like it:

```
public void myService(HashMap<String, String> values) ..
```

I would like to know, how to pass that values using SOAPUI, because it starts with a simple XML like it:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:geps="...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <geps:myService>
         <!--Optional:-->
        <values/>
      </geps:myService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tries use something like this, but my parameter got null :(

```
<values>
<arg0>
<key> 123 </key>
<value> xyz </value>
</arg0>
</values>
```